# a = b edit a without editing b

Tags: python, class, variables, object

If I have a class obj, and I create an instance of that class, bar

```
bar = obj(bar)
```

then `print foo` outputs `foo`

set `foo = bar` then `foo.change(foo)` so that `print foo == 'foo'`

finally i do `print foo, bar` and expect to see `foobar` but i see
`foofoo`. how can i achieve what i want?

I have already tried to do foo = copy.copy(bar) but it will still change both if i change one.
i have even tried to set foo = obj(bar.attribute) and still no.

by the way that isnt the real class i created i just did this because i didnt want to comlicate things more

Comment: Could you please provide a slightly less... abstract example? Is this a custom class? Does it implement `__copy__`? What kind of attributes does it have? Could you give a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make a *deep* copy, using [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy); `copy.copy()` produces just a *shallow* copy:

```
import copy

foo = copy.deepcopy(bar)
```

A shallow copy just recreates the instance but shares all attributes; if those attributes are mutable both `foo` and `bar` see the changes; only if you rebound the attributes on `bar` would `foo` not see the same change.

`copy.deepcopy()` on the other hand recursively creates new copies of anything mutable, producing an entire new structure.